# How to create nested tables in SQLite database?? (android)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, nested

i want to create a nested sqlite database in android.
ie. I want a particular field in a table to have its whole new set of values in the form of a distinct table.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What you're describing isn't possible; there is no way to include a table within a row in another table. Standard practice is to create "parent/child" tables by including the primary key of the parent table as a column in the child table; for instance:

```
PARENT TABLE

id | name
---------
1  | Fred
2  | Bob
```

---

```
CHILD TABLE
id | parent_id | name
---------------------
1  | 1         | John
2  | 1         | Jim
3  | 2         | Joe
4  | 2         | Jane
```

This pair of tables would have "John" and "Jim" as the children of "Fred", and "Joe" and "Jane" as children of "Bob". You could get the set of all children of "Bob" (parent id=2) with the query:

```
SELECT * FROM child_table WHERE parent_id = 2
```

Comment: Okay . i am using this way only. Thanx

Comment: Thanks that was the answer I was looking for!

Comment: Another example is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949917/creating-a-table-inside-a-table-in-sqlite-3-python

Comment: Here,  you are directly querying the child table. how do we dynamically give the parent_id value to this query. I mean, how do we ask - "output the children's names of Bob" for example, instead of asking "output the names whose parent_id is 2"?

Answer (score 0):

That is what i was going to do but You won't be able to create another sub-table of the current table.

I will suggest you to create two different table from it, e.g.. if you have table employee and need to create another two sub-table marketing employee and engineering employee tables, just create the two table that i was describing. e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE emp_engineer
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE emp_marketing
```