# Creating a table inside a table in sqlite 3 (python)

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a sqlite database for a recipe storing program, that holds in the recipe table, the number of people, ingredients, cooking temperature and cooking time. I intend on creating another table inside the ingredients part, to store the 'id' (which will auto increment); the mass number (for example, 200); the mass type (for example, g) and the food type (for example, flour).

I'm using this code to try to get the variables and to store them:

```
    def setIngredientsInRecipe(recipeName):
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO %s(ingredients) CREATE TABLE\
                    (ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, MassNumber VARCHAR(10), MassType VARCHAR(50) FoodType VARCHAR(50))""" % (recipeName))
        print ""
        massNoInput = raw_input("Please enter your first ingredient mass(just the number): ")
        massTypeInput = raw_input("Now please input the mass type (grams etc): ")
        foodInput = raw_input("Please enter your first ingredient type: ")

        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO %s(ingredients(MassNumber)) VALUES('%s')""" % (recipeName,massNoInput))
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO %s(ingredients(MassType)) VALUES('%s')""" % (recipeName,massTypeInput))
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO %s(ingredients(FoodType)) VALUES('%s')""" % (recipeName,foodInput))

        return recipeName
```

Obviously I'm going to add some number checks in later, to see if the input is valid first.

It's crashing out on the first cursor.execute line, saying that it's a syntax error...

If anyone could explain to my how to fix this, I'd be most grateful, I've been looking at this bit of code for ages!

Thanks,
Ryan :)

Comment: You cannot insert a table into another row.. Your SQL syntax is not valid.

Comment: Okay, so I need to think of another way of doing that then... thanks anyway :)

Comment: Create *one* table and insert your data into that table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two tables, one for recipes, and one for ingredients, and have for each ingredient record the ID of the recipe it belongs to:

```sql
CREATE TABLE recipe(ID, People, CookingTime);
CREATE TABLE ingredient(ID, RecipeID, MassNumber, MassType, FoodType);
```

To add one ingredient to a recipe, just insert one record into that table
(here, 42 is the ID of the recipe):

```sql
INSERT INTO ingredient(RecipeID, MassNumber, MassType, FoodType) VALUES (42, ...)
```

Comment: The same thing is described much clearly here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285305/how-to-create-nested-tables-in-sqlite-database-android

Comment: @CL. But How to Join Two Sepeated Table With one Table like parent and Child table https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63830625/android-sqlite-how-to-join-the-second-data-tables-inside-the-first-table