# Android : How to Join the Child Table With Parent Table Sqlite

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

I am New to Android, I created a Simple App for my Learning purpose, the app idea is i am displaying a student informations like `Parent Table` was `College Name`(List of College Names in listview) ->  `Child Table` was `Student Names`(Displaying Students name of that College)

```
1.AnnaUniversity 2.MGRUniversity---->Parent Table
 --------------    --------------
1.arun               1.Raja
2.visnu              2.Bharathi     
3.vihal                          ---->Child Table
```

For that i Created a Two Tables(College Name and Students Name)  in SQlite in Single Datbase called "Details.db"

in `First Activity`  I get the User Input of College Name and Stored in SQlite and Display that in Listview

When the `First Activity` ListViewitem `is Clciked` a Custom Dialog is Called there User enter the Students Name of that College it stored in to the Second Table and  Display that in `Second Activity`of Listview along with CheckBox

**The Problem is the Students Names are Stored inside the Second Table and it doesn't display according to the college name also Not Showing in listview of second activity** ex : Inside AnnaUniversity Parent Table i Add Some Names(child table) it Stored into the Database But It Doesnt Display According to the Names of the parent

[image]

**DatabaseHelper**

```
     // Database Name
            public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "details.db";
        
            // Table 1
            public static final String TABLE_NAME = "CollegeName";
            public static final String COLUMN_ID = "ID";
            public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "college_NAME";
            private static final String COLUMN_IMAGE = "image_bitmap";
        
            // Table 2
            private static final String TABLE2_NAME = "studentsName";
            public static final String COLUMN1_ID = "ID";
            public static final String COLUMN2_TITLE = "students_NAME";


    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    
            String query =
                    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                            + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  ,"
                             + COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT, "
                    + COLUMN_IMAGE + " BLOB )";
    
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);
    
            String query1 =
                    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE2_NAME + "("
                            + COLUMN1_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,"
                            + COLUMN2_TITLE + "  TEXT )";
    
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query1);
    
    
        }
 /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Creating a College Name ( College Name was Saved in College table  ) 

    void createlist(String title, byte[] image) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(COLUMN_TITLE, title);
        cv.put(COLUMN_IMAGE, image);
        Long result = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        if (result == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "College Name Created Sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    // Read ( Displaying the saved  College Names)


    Cursor readAllData() {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = null;
        if (db != null) {
            cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        }
        return cursor;
    }


    // Creating a second table Students Name ( Students Name was Saved in student table ) 

        void itemlist(String items) {
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

            cv.put(COLUMN2_TITLE, items);

            Long result = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE2_NAME, null, cv);
            if (result == -1) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Students name Added Sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    // Read ( Displaying the saved  students Names)

    Cursor readlistAllData() {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE2_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = null;
        if (db != null) {
            cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        }
        return cursor;
    }
```

**AddStudents:**

```
public class AddStudents extends AppCompatActivity {

   
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;
    DatabaseHelper myDB;
    ArrayList<String> listitems;
    StudentsCustomAdapter sca;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_items);

        

      FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_button);



        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

         // Custom Dialog is Called when Plus Button is Clicked to add Students Name inside the Selected College Name
                ShowPopup();

            }
        });


        myDB = new DatabaseHelper(AddStudents.this);

        listitems = new ArrayList<>();

        DisplayList();

        sca = new StudentsCustomAdapter(AddStudents.this,listitems);
    }


  // Displaying the Students Name 

    private void DisplayList(){

        Cursor cursor = myDB.readlistAllData();
        if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "No Data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                listitems.add(cursor.getString(1));
            }
        }
    }

//adding a Students name in custom dialog 
    private void ShowPopup() {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog.show();
        final EditText lname = dialog.findViewById(R.id.list_Edit_txt);
        Button add = dialog.findViewById(R.id.add);
        Button cancel = dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });


        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               

                String name = lname.getText().toString();
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(lname.getText().toString())) {
                    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
                    db.itemlist(name);
                    Toast.makeText(AddItems.this, "Students Added Sucessfully !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else
                    Toast.makeText(AddItems.this, "The name cannot be empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });
    }
```

**Students Custom Adapter**

```
public class StudentsCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> listitem_name;


    public StudentsCustomAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> listnames)
    {
        this.context=c;
        this.listitem_name=listnames;
        this.mInflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listitem_name.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override

    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        if (view == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_items, viewGroup, false);

        }
        CheckBox checkBox = view.findViewById(R.id.cheeckbox);
        TextView listitemnames = view.findViewById(R.id.listitem_name);

        listitemnames.setText((CharSequence) listitem_name);

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the college name as a foreign key in the student table
make sure your both column table have different column name
just make sure COLUMN_ID = "id" than COLUMN_ID ="s_id"

// Database Name
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "details.db";

```
        // Table 1
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "CollegeName";
        public static final String COLUMN_ID = "c_ID";
        public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "college_NAME";
        private static final String COLUMN_IMAGE = "image_bitmap";
    
        // Table 2
        private static final String TABLE2_NAME = "studentsName";
        public static final String COLUMN1_ID = "s_ID";
        public static final String COLUMN2_TITLE = "students_NAME";


public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

        String query =
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                        + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  ,"
                         + COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT, "
                + COLUMN_IMAGE + " BLOB );";

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);

        String query1 =
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE2_NAME + "("
                        + COLUMN1_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,"
                        + COLUMN2_TITLE + "  TEXT ,"
                        + COLUMN_C_ID + " INTEGER, " + "FOREIGN KEY("+ 
                   COLUMN_C_ID +") " 
     + "REFERENCES " + TABLE_NAME +"("+COLUMN_ID +")"+ ");";


        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query1);

    }
```

Comment: It Shows Error that  `TABLE_NAME.COLUMN_ID`  **cannot resolve COLUMN_ID ** 

 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xz0Ig.jpg

Comment: you have missing + after second column name and change the column name

Comment: public static final String SQL_CREATE =
            "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_RECORD +"("+
                    COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                    COLUMN_RECORD_INFO + " TEXT," +
                    COLUMN_RECORD_AMOUNT + " TEXT," +
                    COLUMN_RECORD_DATE + " TEXT," +
                    COLUMN_CATEGORY_ID + " INTEGER, " + "FOREIGN KEY("+ RecordCategoryTable.COLUMN_ID+") " + "REFERENCES " + TABLE_RECORD +"("+COLUMN_CATEGORY_ID+")"+ ");";

Comment: I Changed  `public static final String COLUMN_ID = "C_ID";` and  `public static final String COLUMN1_ID = "S_ID";` After Update it Shows the Same Error  [link] https://i.stack.imgur.com/aASoW.jpg

Comment: What Will Happen if i use `"FOREIGN KEY("+ TABLE_NAME+") " 
     + "REFERENCES "` inisit of `"FOREIGN KEY("+ TABLE_NAME.COLUMN_ID+") " 
     + "REFERENCES "`

Comment: just try to change the column name that you want to use as foreign key

Comment: or i send tou make code and you just change column name in it