# How get SQL-object data out of cursor in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am building an application that requires the use of object-oriented SQL. I have columns of arrays of SQL-objects, wrappers for primitives and strings. I know how to create these objects using SQL statements but I do not know how to actually get these things out of the database in android using a query, and it does not seem like those methods are available in a cursor.

Is it possible to implement a database that has object oriented SQL in it on Android?

Object oriented SQL is where you may create and use different Types to store information. See here:https://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_object_oriented.htm

Comment: What is "object-oriented SQL"? And what are "SQL-objects"?

Comment: PL/SQL is specific to Oracle. And T-SQL is specific to MS SQL Server. SQLite (the default database used in Android) doesn't support these supersets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so object oriented sql is not supported in SQLite. In place of an wrapper object, it is best to have a second table that contains information that would otherwise be in that object, and have that table be the "child" of the first table.

That child relationship is established by the child having a column with the parent's id number, as per this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11285360/7356414

Comment: So you discovered the **R** in **RDBMS**... and is this your answer? If so, accept it - in order to remove your post from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'object-oriented SQL', but it seems to me that you are looking for kind of an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) solution. Please check this one: http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml